# Returning JsonResult is giving Server 500 error?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-2

First attempt at MVC. Attempting to return a JsonResult. I have this in my controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult GetHistoricalReports()
{
    JsonResult result = Json("test");
    //JsonResult result = Json(DashboardSessionRepository.Instance.HistoricalReports);

    return result;
}
```

and in my view:

```
function OnHistoricalListBoxLoad(historicalListBox) {
    $.getJSON('GetHistoricalReports', function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
```

I have a break-point set inside of GetHistoricalReports and it is indeed being hit. The alert in OnHistoricalListBoxLoad never displays, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to return your result like:

```
return Json("test", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of a site that has a good explanation of this? I did some googling for Json, JsonResult, Json Example, etc.. but all the examples seem to be of the javascript-side.

Comment: I think it is to stop requests from outside your site from calling this Action.  See the Haack http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx

Comment: Isnt it the task of [HttpPost] and [HttpGet] to either forbid or allow GET?

Comment: Yes, but this is an additional security setting.  Read the article I posted before.